# VB6 process with application manifest takes a long time to exit

Tags: vb6, winsxs

We maintain a legacy VB6 app. Up through version X it was installed by registering all its COM dependencies. From versions >X we started shipping it with an application manifest instead.

The versions >X in some scenarios **take ~30 seconds longer for the main EXE process to terminate** than versions ≤X. (This effect is visible in Windows Task Manager).

Its just a hunch that it was the change to the manifest which introduced the delay. There were other changes in the app also, but none which seem like they could be related.

---

Note: The scenario where it terminates quickly is where it is executed and then quit right away. But the delay is introduced by a certain set of actions which open data files by calling through some other VB6 COM DLLs, reading some MDBs with DAO, etc. None of this has changed for many versions of the app.

The same scenario did NOT cause a delay in versions ≤X.

So it is not known precisely which line of code directly leads to the delay occurring or not. Before I spend potentially a lot of time tracing it I am looking for input to confirm or deny this manifest hypothesis.

Comment: First thing to do would be to isolate the changes. Make a copy of version >X, rip out the changes except for the manifest, and see if you can still reproduce the slowness. This is the only way you're going to be able to make a [mcve], which we really need in order to provide good answers to this question.

Comment: @CodyGray yes I agree with that in principle; but in order to save some significant hours or days of work it seemed worth posing the question here first. Someone who has seen this pattern before might provide a crucial shortcut.

Comment: 30 seconds seems bizarre.  I'd expect some extra process-teardown overhead to unload your private assemblies, but nothing like that delay.  This sounds like something for a real "forum" site where you could post an example exhibiting the problem and crowdsource some help with it.  SO is meant for simpler issues, more or less to help learning-impaired people too lazy or incompetent to Read That Fine Manual.